# What's wrong when running commandline perl here?

Tags: perl

```
[root@dev-test test]$ perl -e "%hash=(key,1);print 1 if exists $hash{key};"
exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element at -e line 1.
```

The above works if I put it in a file,but why command line fails?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double to prevent shell interpolation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$hash` is being treated by the shell as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (windows). Perhaps in your OS you need to use single quotes? Looks like linux/unix, and double quotes expand variables prefixed with the `$` dollar sign.